# CMake Fortran Module Directory to be used with add_library

Tags: module, cmake, fortran

I have a CMake 3.5.2 project that creates a library: libtest.a, which is then linked to by an executable.

The source code is Fortran, and the libtest.a produces a module file: "main.mod"

The executable also needs to include this main.mod file, so to make main.mod accessible, when building the project I set the variable, CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY to a known location, and add it to the relevant include paths.

This works great when building the entire project, main.mod is built in a known location, and it is there for whatever code needs it. My usage, however, makes it necessary to only build libtest.a by itself, and leave the executable to be built by a downstream user sometimes.

The issue I am having is that when I go into the libtest source and treat it as its own CMake project, the library will build and install, but the main.mod file is always left in the BINARY_DIR and is not built in the CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY, dispite setting in the the CMakeList.txt within libtest.

Is the Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY only honored when add_executable() is being called? And just ignored for the library builds alone? Or am I missing something.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: This will reproduce my issue.

test_mod.f90:

```
module main
 implicit none
 real, parameter :: pi=3.2
end module main
```

tt.f90:

```
program test
  use main
  implicit none
  real :: a, area
  a =10
  area = a * 100
end program test
```

CMakeList.txt:

```
CMAKE_minimum_required( VERSION 3.5 )
enable_language( Fortran )
project( tt )
file( GLOB test_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.f90 )
add_library( tt STATIC ${test_SOURCES} )
set( CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Mod )
install( TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Lib/ )
```

If I build and install the above code, I will get a libtt.a library installed in the Lib directory, however my main.mod will remain in my build directory and is not build in a Mod folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I assume that the "user" uses cmake to build the project while having access to the source of your project.

The steps to a working build.

1. There is a `CMakeLists.txt` file for libtest that specifies `CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY`. This should be enough for `main.mod` to appear there.
2. There is a `CMakeLists.txt` file for buiding the "client" program. This file should include the libtest project with `add_subdirectory`.
3. Add `target_link_libraries(NAME_OF_PROGRAM NAME_OF_LIBRARY)`. This only takes care of the linking of libraries and is not sufficient (for solution B below anyway) for the module to be known to the client program.

Now, make your own adventure:

Solution A: in the libtest `CMakeLists.txt`, place the module where "all modules will go", for instance `set(CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/modules)` (you need to do this also for the "client" `CMakeLists.txt`). The variable `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` is set by the "client" cmake invocation and will be the same for all included cmake projects. This directory will be listed in the build commands for Fortran programs.

Solution B: in the libtest `CMakeLists.txt`, place the module of this library in a dedicated directory. You can achieve this, for instance, with `set(CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/modules)`. You need then to manually specify this location with `include_directories(PATH_THAT_DEPENDS_ON_THE_NAME_OF_THE_SUBPROJECT)` *in the client `CMakeLists.txt`*.

If you wish the library to be *installable*, you need to specify paths for installing the library *and* the module file. With Fortran, you should think of this with the target OS, compiler and architecture in mind.

Links to the CMake documentation:

- [PROJECT_BINARY_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/PROJECT_BINARY_DIR.html)
- [CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY.html)
- [CMAKE_BINARY_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html)

Following the addition of your sample code, the following modification should do it:

```
CMAKE_minimum_required( VERSION 3.5 )
enable_language( Fortran )
project( tt )

set( CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Mod )

file( GLOB test_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.f90 )

add_library( tt STATIC ${test_SOURCES} )

install( TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Lib/ )

install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

1. Make sure that `set( CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Mod )` occurs before any `add_library` line.
2. Add `install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` to actually install the `.mod` file. Module files (as header files in C) have to installed in addition to the library file.

The setup you created is a bit unusual in that you locate everything within the source build whereas "usual" install locations are made relative to [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response Pierre. My setup is similar to your solution B. My issue is that CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY does not actually place the output main.mod in the proper location when I build the library by itself. **IF I build the library under the main executable as a subdirectory/dependency, then everything works great.

Comment: The case where it works is probably because, by coincidence, `main.mod` is somewhere the compiler sees (`${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` for instance) and not because things are set up properly.  I will check the sample you posted.

Comment: That may be possible, but unlikely because in this situation "works" means having a file called main.mod show up in a directory I am expecting it to. I am not having build errors or include errors, when it works I end up with a main.mod file in my CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY and when it does not work, my CMAKE_F_M_D is empty and the main.mod is still sitting in my CMAKE_BINARY_DIR. Thanks again for looking at this.

Comment: I did test the configuration file that I posted online. Did you test my proposal?

Comment: Oh I didn't see the addition. I have tested it and the only modification needed was putting the set(CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY) **before** the add_library command. Now it works as expected. Thanks you so much for the help!!